# Gulp: how do I pipe through a task that never finishes?

Tags: node.js, stream, gulp, browserify, watchify

I'm trying to write a gulp plugin for `watchify` that allows me to pipe files into it.  The problem is that my task never actually "finishes", as it sits there and monitors a bunch of files and re-builds as necessary.

So how do I send code "through" this plugins?

Right now, my task calling the plugin is simplified to:

```
gulp.src( '/path/to/js/*.js' )
    .pipe( watchifyPlugin() )
    .pipe( cfg.gulp.dest( '/path/to/build' ) )
```

My `watchifyPlugin` is:

```
module.exports = function( opts ){
    return through.obj( function( file, enc, cb ){
        // watchify file
        self.push( data ); // whenever any .js files are updated

        // never call cb()
    }
}
```

Now this works fine for the first `.js` file that my glob finds.  Any other files never actually get to my plugin, however, and I'm assuming it's because I never call `cb()`.

So how do I do this?  Is there a way to keep writing to the stream without calling `cb()`, which closes it, yet still allow the previous pipes to continue?

in other words:

- index.js

  - `watchify()`
  - pipes to `dest()` just fine, even when I call `self.push()` again and again
  - `cb()` never called
- index2.js

  - `watchify()` never called until `cb()` called for `index.js`, but this "closes" the `index.js` pipe

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad idea.  Not everything in gulp needs to be a plugin, and in particular, browerify and watchify plugins are consistently banned.  (See https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json.)  If you want to run watchify, just use watchify directly.  From https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var watchify = require('watchify');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  var bundler = watchify('./src/index.js');

  // Optionally, you can apply transforms
  // and other configuration options on the
  // bundler just as you would with browserify
  bundler.transform('brfs');

  bundler.on('update', rebundle);

  function rebundle () {
    return bundler.bundle()
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
  }

  return rebundle();
});
```

Comment: No, it's not a "very bad idea".  The whole point of making this a plugin is to get away from the anti-pattern of defining a specific output file in the task.

Comment: The `browserify` stream would only emit *one* file ever and it has to have a name, I don't see how that is an anti-pattern. (You can always require a config.json and configure your filename there)

Comment: That's the point -- it only ever emits one file.  That's a very, very narrow use case, even if it is a common one.  I want a pipe that emits multiple bundled files.

Answer (score 0):

You are using through in a wrong way, you *must* call the callback when you are done with the file ('data' event). However it is not `cb()` that closes the stream, it is emitting the `end` even that does this.

You can delay the end event and keep calling `this.push` to send out new files.

Something like

```
var Through = require('through2').obj;
var my_plugin = function() {

  var last_file = null; // as an example, last emitted file

  function handle_data = function(file, enc, done) { 
    this.push(file); // emit the file
    this.push(file); // just for kicks, emit it again
    last_file = file;
    done(); // done handling *this* file
  }

  function handle_end = function(done) {
     if(last_file) this.push(last_file); // emit the last file again
     done(); // handled the 'end' event
  }

  return Through(handle_data, handle_end);
}
```

This would emit each file twice before processing the next file, then when it's done with all files (the `end` event is received) it emits the last file one more time and then emits the `end` event.

But why are you not using `gulp.watch` and just run the task again when something has changed? or even use the [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch) plugin which emits files when they changed?

Comment: I know I can delay the event, but the point is that I need to delay it _forever_.  `watchify` keeps monitors open on all of the nested required JS files and rebuilds the parent one when any of them change.  Initializing this in `gulp.watch` has two downsides -- It doesn't monitor included files, and it will do a full rebuild each time instead of an incremental one.

Comment: which event? `end` or `data`? The streams are always data-data-data-data-end or for continuous streams: data-data-data ... So if you want to delay a data event forever (effectively making the stream continuous), you *need* to consume and don't emit the `end` event (so don't call `done()` in `handle_end`). And you *need* to call `done()` in the data event (wether you emit or not). Then you can emit whatever files you want from your stream. But still, I fail to see how this is much different from `gulp-watch`, maybe you can expand your question? Finally, I agree with @robrich answer.